# De-authorize C# API endpoint

Tags: c#, authorization

I created an API whose endpoints are only available to registered users. The API is therefore protected by `[Authorize]` attribute in front of the class name, however I have one endpoint method that I would like to expose to everybody.

Obviously an easy solution would be to apply the attribute to each method separately, but it seems "ugly" to write `Authorize` 20 times for each method just so that I can have that one method unprotected.

**Is it possible to de-authorize a single method in an `Authorize`d class?**

Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: [OverrideAuthorizationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.overrideauthorizationattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! `AllowAnonymous` did the trick - no idea why I didn't think of searching keyword `anonymous` ...